# How to set geolocations automatically and create a geofence in the background in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

For a current project I am trying to create a geofence around all hospitals and emergency rooms. I am trying to make the app alert the user if he/she enters a geofence of a hospital. I have I good idea of how to set geofences but I am unsure how to automatically set them on all hospitals.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/136165/core-location-geofencing-tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost: you cannot set this up as a one-time geofence. There can only be 20 active geofences at any time from your app. There are a lot more than 20 hospitals in the world.

I don't know if you have a list of hospitals already, or if that's the question. If you want to get a somewhat accurate list, then you'll want to make a `MKLocalSearch` to find ones nearby. If this isn't accurate enough, you'll have to compile your own database of locations.

You can use the results to set up geofences for the 20 closest hospitals.

You can then use `CLLocationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()` to detect when the device has moved substantially (this often happens when you change cell towers). You can then search again and reestablish geofences for the current 20 closest hospitals.